# Why is there no libiconv package in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, iconv

Many programs rely on libiconv support.
Having to compile it on our own means to recompile a lot of things on every update.

Why is there no packet or has it a different name?

Comment: Is this sufficient? http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libiconv&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: Did you try asking apt? `apt search libiconv`

Comment: @M.Becerra lib-iconv-hook is something different.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`libiconv` is included in the `libc6` package as a GNU standard C library.

In case one needs the header files from originally `libiconv-dev`, use `libc6-dev` instead where the iconv header files are included.